# How to create a mat from bits in opencv for java?

Tags: java, opencv, feature-descriptor

can somebody explain how to create a binary mat with values from a bitstring?

For example,
I want to create my Mat from bitstrings `11110000`and `01010101`, so I have a mat object with 2 rows and 1 colum.

For this I initialize the mat-object with `Mat mat = new Mat(2,1,CvType.CV_8UC1);`

Can I convert these strings to a byte array and use `mat.put(0,0,bytearray)` or is there something else that I must conside?

Later I want to use this approach to create my own `binary descriptor` that can compare wth other descriptors, extracted by `ÒRB`.
With `norm(descA,descB,NORM_HAMMING)`

thank you and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Byte.parseByte()` with a `radix` of 2 e.g `byte b = Byte.parseByte(str, 2);` to first convert it to `byte` and then create a byte array and then covert it to `Mat` object as below:

```
Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(byteArray), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: Why can tell me the reason, I have developed applications that uses this line of code and currently running on the server, I just copy and paste that line of code from my project, so it means that this is OK perfectly!

Comment: think of meaning of decode. there is no data to decode here. maybe you use it in your code to decode an image data for example a jpeg

Comment: hello, so I think that a `new MatOfByte(byteArray)` command is enough. But what's the different between MatByte() and a simple Mat() object in this case?

Comment: No it is not enough, it must be decoded, `MatOfByte` is OpenCV data type extending `Mat` class, So it has some functionality than `Mat`. And also the decoding function also need this kind of data type.